# Streamlabs Even List with photos

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here there,

I'm trying to customize streamlabs event list in order to show followers pictures beside the event message.
I don't have any idea about doing that cause i don't know how to get the avatars picture from facebook.
Here is an exemple about what i'm trying to mean.

All that í've done so far is below

```
  html
    <script type="text/template" id="eventlist_item">
        <li class="{eventType}">
            <div class="background"></div>
            <div>               
                <span class="tag">{tag}</span>
                <span class="message">{from}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </script>
    
       css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@800&display=swap');
    
    
    html, .widget-EventList li > div {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX({rotate_x}) rotateY({rotate_y});
                transform: rotateX({rotate_x}) rotateY({rotate_y});
    }
    
    .widget-EventList, .widget-EventList * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
        color: {text_color};
        background: transparent;
        overflow: hidden;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li {
        width: 25%;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: {show_animation} {animation_speed} forwards;
                animation: {show_animation} {animation_speed} forwards;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li > div:first-child {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: opacity {animation_speed};
                transition: opacity {animation_speed};
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li > div:last-child {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        height: 1.2em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        -webkit-animation: growB {animation_speed} forwards;
                animation: growB {animation_speed} forwards;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li:first-child > div:first-child {
        opacity: 2;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li:first-child > div:last-child {
        -webkit-animation: growA {animation_speed} forwards;
                animation: growA {animation_speed} forwards;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li:nth-child(n+{max_events}) {
        -webkit-animation: {hide_animation} {animation_speed} forwards;
                animation: {hide_animation} {animation_speed} forwards;
    }
    
    
    @-webkit-keyframes growA {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            font-size: 0em;
            height: 0em;
            line-height: 0em;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            padding: 0;
        }
    
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            font-size: 1em;
            height: 1.6em;
            line-height: 1.6em;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    }
    
    
    @keyframes growA {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            font-size: 0em;
            height: 0em;
            line-height: 0em;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            padding: 0;
        }
    
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            font-size: 1em;
            height: 1.6em;
            line-height: 1.6em;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes growB {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            font-size: 1em;
            height: 1.6em;
            line-height: 1.6em;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes growB {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            font-size: 1em;
            height: 1.6em;
            line-height: 1.6em;
        }
    }
    
    .widget-EventList .tag {
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 5px;
        top: 20px;
        right: 15px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList .message {
        padding-right: 15px;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
    
    .widget-EventList li > div:first-child {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    
        Js
    // Please use event listeners to run functions.
    document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj) {
        // obj will be empty for event list
        // this will fire only once when the widget loads
    });
    
    document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
        // obj will contain information about the event
        
    });

[Exemple][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9KzI.png
```